Starting a GUI process on a remote windows computer through SSH
I would like to start a process on a remote computer through SSH and have the GUI of the process open up on one of the remote computer's displays.
The remote computer is running Windows (10 or 11)
Example
To explain what I mean, here is how this works on a linux remote computer (running xserver):

Connect to the linux remote with SSH
set the $DISPLAY environment variable to :0, or whatever the ID of the display is.
Start the process. The process will now appear on the remote computer's screen.

Here's the full command, which I've tested on a remote Ubuntu 22.04 (but it should work on any Linux running xserver):
ssh <remote_user>@<remote_ip> "export DISPLAY=:0 && gedit"

My attempt
In windows, I can start a process in windows remotely with ssh <remote_user>@<remote_ip> "notepad.exe". However, the GUI of the window does not appear on the remote display.
I can see the process appears in the task list, so it is executed fine, but the GUI just doesn't appear.
So, to reiterate my question, how do I make it appear?
And just to be absolutely clear: I do not want the GUI to open on my local PC (the PC that I am connecting from). I want it to appear on the remote display (of the computer that I am connecting to)

What OS for the remote computer?

Remote Desktop is Microsoft's way of accomplishing this.  X11 forwarding is another.  Microsoft has never exposed the api for showing remote RDC windows locally without the host but seemed to be playing with the idea a long time ago.

I dont need any remote desktop or X11 forwarding. Those are both for viewing the remote process locally. I want to view the remote process remotely, i.e. I want it to open up on the display of the computer that I am remotely connected to. (I've edited the original question to make this a bit more clear)

@John any app, for example notepad. I can run this command: ssh localuser@<remote_ip> "notepad.exe" and see that the notepad process is started on the remote windows PC (i can see it in task list), but the notepad window does not appear on the remote PC's screen

@Olli please add the requested additional information to your question, not to comments down here. Your goal needs to be to make your main question post as clear and complete as possible. I see you have edited it, but you have not shown specifics about what you've tried, how you've tried it, and have just given some vague suggestions. Please use specifics in the question itself, as specifics in the question will help us be better able to give specifics in answers.

I've reformulated the question. Hopefully it is more clear now.
